# how to get sorting data by desncending with appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i want to sort the data based on the newest data, but when i input the new data it will be come to the bottom of the page not the top of the page

```
function globalVariables(){ 
  var varArray = {
    spreadsheetId   : '', 
    dataRage        : 'Data!A2:J',                                    
    idRange         : 'Data!A2:A',                                    
    lastCol         : 'J',                                            
    insertRange     : 'Data!A1:J1',                                   
    sheetID         : '0',                                             
  };
  return varArray;
}


function readData(spreadsheetId,range){
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, range);
  return result.values;
}

function getLastTenRows(){
  var lastRow = readData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,globalVariables().dataRage).length -1;
  if(lastRow<=11){
    var range = globalVariables().dataRage;
  }else{
    var range = 'Data!A'+(lastRow-9)+':'+globalVariables().lastCol;
  }
  var lastTenRows = readData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,range);
  return lastTenRows;
}
```

thats the code i used to, i want to sort based the newest data
any solution?

Comment: You have not included functions `globalVariables()` or `readData()` so it is impossible to tell what these are doing and how it affects your script.

Comment: sorry my bad, i just edit to put some function on it

Comment: You do know that lastTenRows is an object not an array?  You would need to access the property lastTenRows.values to get the array of values.